# Login to RTC using oslc and rest

Tags: rest, rational-team-concert, oslc

I am new to Rational team concert.
Please if anyone knows, can you help me how to login to rational team concert using oslc and rest API with so sample code

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**In Python**

```
base_url = "https://jazzccm.domain:9443/ccm"
auth_url = '/authenticated/identity'
workItem_url = "https://jazzccm.domain:9443/ccm/oslc/workitems/"
session = requests.Session()
session.verify = False
session.allow_redirects = True
session.headers = {'accept':'application/json'}
session.auth = (username,password)
# authenticated user
response = session.get(base_url + auth_url)
print(str(response.headers))
print(str(response.status_code))
if 'x-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg' in response.headers and response.headers['x-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg'] == 'authrequired':
    print("Not authenticated yet")
    login_response = session.post(base_url + '/j_security_check', data={'j_username':username, 'j_password':password})
    print(str(login_response.headers))
    print(str(login_response.status_code))
    if 'x-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg' in login_response.headers and login_response.headers['x-com-ibm-team-repository-web-auth-msg'] == 'authrequired':
        print(str(login_response.status_code))
        print("Exit HEre")
        sys.exit(1)
    response = session.get(base_url + auth_url)
response = session.get(workItem_url + number + '.json')
print(str(response.json()))
json_data = response.json()
```

**In DXL**

```
// Usuall Taken from some link or some doors link
resourceURL = "https://jazzccm.domain:9443/ccm/oslc/workitems/number.json"
// create the header
HttpHeader reqHeader = null
// no body is necessary
HttpBody reqBody = null
// send request
HttpResponse resp = HttpRequest(HttpGet, resourceURL, reqBody, reqHeader)
if (resp != null)
{
    HttpHeaderEntry entry
    Buffer buff = create
    buff += "*** STATUS ***\n"
    buff += resp.code "\n"
    buff += "*** HEADER ***\n"
    // another example of the header iterator
    for entry in resp.header do
    {
        buff += entry.key
        buff += ":"
        buff += entry.value
        buff += "\n"
    }
    buff += "*** BODY ***\n"
    HttpBody respBody = resp.body
    if (respBody != null)
    {
        buff += stringOf(respBody.value) ""
    }
    else
    {
        buff += "No body was returned."
    }
    // display the response
    displayRich("\\pard " stringOf(buff))
    // remember to delete the buffer
    delete buff
    // remember to delete the response
    delete resp
}
```